# How do I clone a repository from a point in time using Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, github, repository

I made a couple mistakes in Code in asp.net and pushed to master by mistake. How do I clone a specific repository from a point in using the git hub feature in Visual Studio 2019?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the specific commit SHA then you could use `git checkout <commit id>` in the terminal. It appears this feature is not supported natively in visual studios just yet https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/55086